# relationship between $\sin$ and $\cos$ integrals

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve a physics problem and I end up with the following two equations.

$\int\limits_{0}^{T}\sin\theta(t)dt = a$

and

$\int\limits_{0}^{T}\cos\theta(t)dt = b$

The exact dependence of $\theta(t)$ with $t$ is not exactly known but it can be assumed that $\theta(t)$ has all the nice properties like one-one, onto, continuous, differentiable etc.

I would like to eliminate the integrals and find a relation between $a$ and $b$. However so far I am unable to do this. Any ideas how this could be done? How can I find a relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a relationship between a and b here sir? You wish to form a closed form representation of a and b ?

Comment: yah $a$ as a function of $b$ or the other way.

Comment: $b+ia= \int_{0}^{T}e^{i\theta(t)}dt$ so there is likely no relation between $a$ and $b$, except for special functions $\theta$.